# mod_rewrite Zend Server

Tags: mod-rewrite, localhost, zend-server

Can not get my mod_rewrite to work with Zend Server
My urls are giving the following error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL
>   /forums/main-forum.2/ was not
>   found on this server.

http://pastebin.com/nki3uh8X

this is my http.conf

Cheers

Comment: What are the asked URL? The URL that is in the address bar when you have the error? What is your Rewrites rules (I do not see anything that looks like `RewriteRule XXX YYYY` in you example. What did you tried? And BTW I think that question could be improved in style, it currently looks like `pleaze gimme teh codez`.

Answer (score 5):

You should change:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

in your `http.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Zend Server CE has a section on it's httpd.conf setting AllowOverride for the default www directory to None. On my Zend httpd.conf this is between lines 195 and 220. You must set it to: AllowOverride All in order to mod_rewrite work in the default Zend htdocs directory.

```
<Directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2/htdocs">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All
#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing the httpd.conf in Apache2/conf/hhtpd.conf, I also changed the .htaccess file of the site I was having problems with to include the a piece of the local path as follows:

```
RewriteRule .* /CRC/index.php [L]
```

In my case, I use the Zend Server CE as localhost on my workstation and I have several sites running on the base dir /